# Fast Functional Equivalent Of For Loop Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop, functional-programming

I have the following two code snippets in Scala:

```
/* Iterative */   
for (i <- max to sum by min) {
  if (sum % i == 0) validBusSize(i, L, 0)
}

/* Functional */
List.range(max, sum + 1, min)
    .filter(sum % _ == 0)
    .map(validBusSize(_, L, 0))
```

Both these code snippets are part of otherwise identical objects. However, when I run my code on Hackerrank, the object with the iterative snippet takes a maximum of 1.45 seconds, while the functional snippet causes the code to take > 7 seconds, which is a timeout.

I'd like to know if it's possible to rewrite the for loop functionally while retaining the speed. I took a look at the `Stream` container, but again I'll have to call `filter` before `map`, instead of computing each `validBusSize` sequentially.

Thanks!

Edit:

```
/* Full Code */
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine

object BusStation {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    readLine
    val L = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList

    val min = L.min
    val max = L.max
    val sum = L.foldRight(0)(_ + _)

    /* code under consideration */
    for (i <- max to sum by min) {
      if (sum % i == 0) validBusSize(i, L, 0)
    }
  }

  def validBusSize(size: Int, L: List[Int], curr: Int) {

    L match {        
      case Nil if (curr == size) => print(size + " ") 
      case head::tail if (curr < size) => 
        validBusSize(size, tail, curr + head)
      case head::tail if (curr == size) => validBusSize(size, tail, head)
      case head::tail if (curr > size) => return
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `validBusSize` do? Post the code for that too.

Comment: since you don't return anything from `validBusSize`, you might want to use `foreach` instead of `map`. That way you don't waste time collecting things you can't use. You could try `(max to sum by min).filter(sum % _ == 0).foreach(validBusSize(_, L, 0))`

Comment: The slowness of your functional approach is probably due to the intermediate `List` being created with `filter` and `map`. Try using `List.range(...).view`. See this: http://www.sumologic.com/blog/technology/3-tips-for-writing-performant-scala

Comment: The inserting a `view` before the `filter` doesn't produce any output, but if I then replace the `map` with a `foreach`, the output returns. Neither approach leads to a speed up unfortunately, but I clearly have a lot to learn about Scala.

Comment: The two alternatives are just as functional as each other. The for loop desugars into a map, neither has any mutable state (as part of the iteration, anyway - validBusSize is side-effecting in both cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your best bet for fast functional code is tail-recursive functions:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def getBusSizes(i: Int, sum: Int, step: Int) {
  if (i <= sum) {
    if (sum % i == 0) validBusSize(i, L, 0)
    getBusSizes(i + step, sum, step)
  }
}
```

Various other things will be sort of fast-ish, but for something like this where there's mostly simple math, the overhead from the generic interface will be sizable.  With a tail-recursive function you'll get a while loop underneath.  (You don't need the annotation to make it tail-recursive; that just causes the compilation to fail if it can't.  The optimization happens whether the annotation is there or not.)

Comment: Sweet, thanks a lot! I came up with a solution as well, but using tail recursion is even faster.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently the following worked:

Replacing the `List.range(max, sum + 1, min)` with a Range object, `(max to sum by min)`. Going to ask another questions about why this works though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the range into a parallel version with keyword `par`, for instance like this

```
(max to sum by min).par
```

This may improve performance especially for large sized ranges with large values on calling `validBusSize`.

Thus in the proposed for comprehension,

```
for ( i <- (max to sum by min).par ) {
  if (sum % i == 0) validBusSize(i, L, 0)
}
```